# How do I find out when the Spring.NET root context has loaded?

Tags: spring.net

I have a web service running, and it uses Spring.NET for it's IoCness.  One of the classes needs to do some stuff when it loads (I'm using `AfterPropertiesSet`) and "some stuff" involves a call to `ContextRegistry.GetContext()`.  The problem is this code in the `ContextRegistry` class:

```
if (rootContextCurrentlyInCreation)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("root context is currently in creation. You must not call ContextRegistry.GetContext() from e.g. constructors of your singleton objects");    
}
```

How can I have that object register itself to be notified once the context is fully created?

Answer (score 3):

if possible, remove that call to `ContextRegistry.GetContext()`. That is a sign of bad design anyway because it couples your code very closely to the container - which I think we all agree shouldn't be the case.

What exactly are you trying to do?

**P.S**: I'd also like to suggest you post Spring for .NET relevant questions to our [community forums](http://forum.springframework.net/) - it is more likely to get your questions answered there.